# CAML query using 'contains'

Tags: 2013, 2010, caml-query, caml

I have a CAML query

```
<Query><Where><Or>"+
             "<Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='User'>" + User.Name + "</Value></Eq>"+
             "<Contains><FieldRef Name ='OtherUsers'/><Value Type = 'Note'>" + site.CurrentUser.Name + "</Value></Contains>"+
          "</Or></Where></Query>
```

This works and brings desired results. Now coming to the issue

The **OtherUsers** column holds the list of selected users in .csv format.
Say if User1&User11 are selected the column will contain `User1,User11`

When User11 is selected the column will just have `User11`

Now according to the query, when `User1`  logs in, it will bring the record containing `User11` in `OtherUsers` column as `User11` contains `User1`. 
How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"<Query><Where>"+
                "<Or>"+
                    "<Or>"+
                        "<Or>"+
                             "<Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='User'>" + User.Name + "</Value></Eq>"+
                             "<Contains><FieldRef Name ='OtherUsers'/><Value Type = 'Note'>" + site.CurrentUser.Name + ",</Value></Contains>"+
                        "</Or>"+
                        "<Contains><FieldRef Name='OtherUsers' /><Value Type='Note'>," + site.CurrentUser.Name + "</Contains>"+
                    "</Or>"+
                "<Eq><FieldRef Name='OtherUsers' /><Value Type='Note'>" + site.CurrentUser.Name + "</Value></Eq>"+
                "</Or>"+
            "</Where></Query>"
```

Use this query. It should do the trick

If `user1` logs in below scenarios It will work on:

- `OtherUsers` = `"user1,user11,user12";`
- `OtherUsers` = `"user2,user1,user12";`
- `OtherUsers` = `"user2,user1";`
- `OtherUsers` = `"user1";`

And for `User11` it will work on below scenarios only:

- `OtherUsers` = `"user1,user11,user12";`
- `OtherUsers` = `"user2,user11";`
- `OtherUsers` = `"user11";`

Comment: excellent workaround, 
may be when user1 logs in and OtherUsers = "user12,user11" the condition might fail?

Comment: no it will not fail, it will work

Comment: `"<Contains><FieldRef Name='OtherUsers' /><Value Type='Note'>," + site.CurrentUser.Name + "</Contains></Contains>"`
this condition is true?

Comment: may be I have construct the csv like `,name1,name2,name3` etc so that I can just check for one contains with `","+name+","`

Comment: only 3 which added is sufficient, This condition you mentioned represents, user id must have comma in first and last position

Comment: 2 `</Contains></Contains>` was a typo.. updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45304/discussion-between-gaurravs-and-vignesh).

Answer (score 2):

I had also same problem, But unfortunately you cant check exact match of string  in comma separated value of multilne text.

But alternatively you can achieve this,

1. Use contains operator that gives you a set of result items,
2. Then split items separated by comma and check exact match using script/c#/regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think your value type is wrong. I have developed such kind of CAML query like below:

```
<Contains><FieldRef Name='otherUser' /><Value Type='User'>" + site.CurrentUser.Name + "</Value></Contains>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "In" element

```
<In>
  <FieldRef Name = "Field_Name"/>
  <Values>    <Value Type = "Field_Type"/>
  </Values>  <XML />
</In>
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/in-element-query